# Spring JdbcTemplate transactions

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I need to perform a transaction with spring `@Transactional` annotation. I currently use `GreenPlum` database. I need to perform some DB operations in the same transaction. Here is how it looks like:

```
@Transactional
public void doSome(){
    //query
    new JdbcTemplate(dataSource).query(\*...*\);
    //some another query
    new JdbcTemplate(dataSource).query(\*...*\);
    //some another another query
    new JdbcTemplate(dataSource).query(\*...*\);
}
```

The thing is [***GreenPlum employes autocommit mode***](https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4330/ref_guide/sql_commands/BEGIN.html) so each statement executes in its own transaction.

So what about multiple statements in the same `@Transactional` block?

Does each statement executes in its own transaction or they all execute in the same transaction?

Comment: They should be all in the same transaction, but you probably want to read this http://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring